# Trying to make an Ajax call to my Web API, not working, getting error

Tags: ajax, jquery, asp.net-web-api

Both the WebAPI and the Website are sitting on `localhost:80`, so cross-domain shouldn't be an issue.  Here's my client-side code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'GET',
                url: 'http://localhost/SixFilmWebAPI/api/SixFilm/60',
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) { WriteResponse(data); },
                error: function (err) { alert('error!'); },
            });
        });

        function WriteResponse(actors) {
            var strResult = "<table><th>Name</th><th>Dob</th><th>Dod</th>";
            $.each(actors, function (index, actor) {
                strResult += "<tr><td>" + message.Name + "</td><td> " + message.Dob + "</td></tr>" + message.Dod + "</td></tr>";
            });
            strResult += "</table>";
            $("#divResult").html(strResult);
        }
```

Each time I run my website, the `error` callback function gets hit, but, looking in Fiddler, I am getting my JSON object returned with a 200 OK response.  Manually navigating to the WebAPI URL also returns JSON.  What am I doing wrong???

Comment: What is the error? What do you see in the network tab?

Comment: Hmm, Fiddler sees the JSON object.  I'm trying to get the more detailed error for you, I'm no expert with Ajax.

Comment: Look at the `err` parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Both the WebAPI and the Website are sitting on localhost:80, so cross-domain shouldn't be an issue.

In this case use relative url:

```
url: '/SixFilmWebAPI/api/SixFilm/60'
```

Then open your web browsers developer toolbar and inspect the Network tab. For example in Google Chrome's developer toolbar you will see the exact request being sent to the server and the response status code and body. This would give you a pretty good indication of what might have gone wrong.

Also place breakpoints inside your controller action and see if it gets hit. If it doesn't it's a routing or binding issue. In all cases the developer toolbar of your browser will help you sort it out. Also keep an eye on the `Console` tab which is where potential javascript errors and XHR warnings will be shown. Then look inside the `success` callback. Does it get hit? Did you return a JSON array from your Web API? Because from what I can see you are attempting to loop through the `actors` variable over there. So make sure that your server returned a JSON like this:

```
[
    { "Name":"foo", "Dob":"2010-11-01", "Dod":"2013-07-01" },
    { "Name":"bar", "Dob":"1967-05-17", "Dod":"2001-04-21" }
]
```

Comment: Fiddler shows a 200 OK response and it shows my JSON object from the WebAPI call... weird, still looking to see why my error callback is being hit.

Comment: So this is a strong indication that the error is somewhere inside the success callback. My questions are in the answer: 1. Does this callback gets hit? 2. Does your JSON response represents a javascript array where each element is an object with `Name`, `Dob` and `Dod` properties? 3. Can you see some javascript error in the `Console` tab of your developer toolbar? I mean doing web development and not using a developer toolbar in the webbrowser will make this web development a very tedious experience.

Comment: Ahh.. so apparently I'm using port 2202... Console tab shows: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/SixFilmWebAPI/api/SixFilm/60. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:2202' is therefore not allowed access. 

I think this is a good starting point for me.

Comment: See how easy it is to make web development with the right tools? The first thing I suggested in my answer is to use a relative url to ensure that there are no cross domain AJAX requests. Now if you need to use cross domain AJAX requests you might need to enable CORS.